# What happens if I carry an item for someone else when entering Singapore and do not know what it contains?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, luggage, singapore

I read on https://eservices.ica.gov.sg/sgarrivalcard (the quote can be seen when filling in the forms):

> If you are bringing in any item, or carrying an item for someone else, but you do not know what it contains, you must declare the item at the Red Channel.

This surprised me as I believe some countries insist that passengers must only bring their own luggage, and not somebody else's. The quote applies for air entries. I don't know if it also applies for sea/land entries.

What happens if I carry an item for someone else when entering Singapore and do not know what it contains? Do the Red Channel officers check it and:

- let me enter Singapore with it if the Red Channel officers are ok with the content;
- let me enter Singapore without it or only part of it, if the Red Channel officers are not ok with all the content

? Or do the Red Channel officers throw away any item/luggage that isn't mine? Or something else?

Comment: Would you really carry an unknown object or substance across an international border? That seems extremely unwise.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137680/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-what-happens-if-i-carry-an-item-for).

Answer (score 9):

If you declare that you don't know what you're bringing, it will be inspected, it may be confiscated, and you may be liable for prosecution based on whatever laws you may have broken.

Obviously, if you're truly gullible enough to take someone else's stuff across the border, you'll also declare it following this guidance, and allow authorities to investigate what it is you're bringing and why.

If, on the other hand, you're a contraband smuggler who intends to claim "someone gave it to me and I don't know what it is" when caught, then that excuse is preempted by this rule and another charge will be added to the list when you're prosecuted.

***Note: Drug trafficking in Singapore comes with death penalty. No amount of monetary compensation is worth to bring someone else's goods via SG customs.***